# how to get radio button valuse and store in mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, xaml, windows-store-apps, radio-button

i want to store the radio button values as male and female in the mysql database, therefore i used windows store application using c#

here is my C# code

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string Query = @"INSERT INTO `bcasdb`.`tbl_student`
                    (`reg_id`,
                    `std_fname`,
                    `std_lname`,
                    `tbl_batch_batch_id`,
                    `gender`) 
        VALUES (@regId, @fName, @lName, @bID, @gender)";
           //This is command class which will handle the query and connection object.
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(BCASApp.DataModel.DB_CON.connection);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regId", this.regIDInput.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", this.fnameInput.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", this.lnameInput.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bID", this.batchIDInput.Text);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", );
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            successmsgBox();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            errormsgBox();
        }
    }

    private void genderInput_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

here is my xaml coding

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,20,0,10">
                <RadioButton Name="maleInput" Content="Male" Checked="genderInput_Checked" Width="75"></RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Name="femaleInput" Content="Female" Checked="genderInput_Checked" Width="162"></RadioButton>
            </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string gender = maleInput.IsChecked ? "M" : "F";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
```

Assumes that a selection is required. If making no selection is valid:

```
string gender = null;
if (maleInput.IsChecked || femaleInput.IsChecked) {
    gender = maleInput.Checked ? "M" : "F";
}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
```

Comment: Good grief, the code was provided as a sample of what you need to do, if you are not able to figure it out from what was provided there is little hope. Even so I have modified the sample so you can now cut and paste to your own code without having to exercise any thought or judgment...

Comment: im developing windows store app using vs 2013